# How to return selenium browser (or how to import a def that return selenium browser)

Tags: python, selenium, return, phantomjs, definition

I would like to start a selenium browser with a particular setup (privoxy, Tor, randon user agent...) in a function and then call this function in my code. I have created a python script `mybrowser.py` with this inside:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

class MyBrowserClass:
    def start_browser():
        service_args = [
            '--proxy=127.0.0.1:8118',
            '--proxy-type= http',
            ]
        dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (UserAgent().random)

        browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = service_args,         desired_capabilities=dcap)
        return browser

    def set_new_ip():
        with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
            controller.authenticate(password=password) 
            controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Then I import it into another script `myscraping.py` with this inside:

```
import mybrowser
import time

browser= mybrowser.MyBrowserClass.start_browser()
browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")
print(browser.page_source)
mybrowser.MyBrowserClass.set_new_ip()
time.sleep(12) 
browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")
print(browser.page_source)
```

The browser is working - I can access the page and retrieve it with `.page_source`.

But the IP doesn't change between the first and the second print. If I move the content of the function inside `myscraping.py` (and remove the import + function call) then the IP change.

Why? Is it a problem with returning the browser? How can I fix this?

---

Actually, the situation is a bit more complex. When I connect to `https://check.torproject.org` before and after the call to `mybrowser.set_new_ip()` and the `wait of 12 sec` (cf the lines below), the IP given by the webpage changes between the first and the second call. So my Ip is changed (according to Tor) but neither `https://httpbin.org/ip` nor `icanhazip.com` detects the change in the IP.

```
...
browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")
print(browser.page_source)
browser.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]').text )
mybrowser.set_new_ip()
time.sleep(12) 
browser.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
print(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="content"]').text )
browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")
print(browser.page_source)
```

So the IP that are printed are like that:

```
42.38.215.198 (canihazip before mybrowser.set_new_ip() )
42.38.215.198  (check.torproject before mybrowser.set_new_ip() )
106.184.130.30  (check.torproject after mybrowser.set_new_ip() )
42.38.215.198 (canihazip after  mybrowser.set_new_ip())
```

---

Privoxy configuration: in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy\config.txt`, I have uncommented this line (9050 is the port Tor uses):

```
forward-socks5t   /               127.0.0.1:9050
```

Tor configuration: in `torcc`, I have this:

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword : xxxx
```

Comment: Does `browser.refresh()` after the `browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")` effect the reported IP?

Comment: `browser.refresh()` doesn't affect the result (I tried after `browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")`and also just after `mybrowser.set_new_ip()` ).

Comment: Okay, how about re-creating the browser instance - `browser.close()` and then `browser= mybrowser.start_browser()` and `browser.get("https://canihazip.com/s")` again?

Comment: Also, if possible please post your privoxy+tor configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, `browser.close()` and then `browser= mybrowser.start_browser()` is working. Although it's not ideal. Still I dont' understand why I need to restart the browser and also it doesn't solve the mystery about tor seeing the IP change but not `canihazip.com` when I don't restart the browser.

Comment: I have added my privoxy+tor configuration at the bottom of my question

Comment: The title of this question doesn't really represent the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *probably* because of PhantomJS keeping a **memory cache** of requested content. So your first visit using a PhantomJS browser can have a dynamic result but that result is then cached and each consecutive visit uses that cached page.

This **memory cache** has caused issues like `CSRF-Token`'s not changing on refresh and now I believe it is the root cause of your problem. The [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10357) was presented and resolved in 2013 but the solution is a method, `clearMemoryCache`, found in PhantomJS's `WebPage` class. Sadly, we are dealing with a Selenium `webdriver.PhantomJS` instance.

So, unless I am overseeing something, it'd be tough to access this method through Selenium's abstraction.

The only solution I see fit is to use another webdriver that doesn't have a **memory cache** like PhantomJS's. I have tested it using Chrome and it works perfectly:

```
103.***.**.***
72.***.***.***
```

Also, as a side note, Selenium is phasing out PhantomJS:

> `UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check if a new nym is available or not.

[is_newnym_available](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html) - true if tor would currently accept a NEWNYM signal

`if controller.is_newnym_available():
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)`